# How to set the Internal format and format for the glTexImage function

Tags: opengl, textures

I am receiving pixel data in BGRA format.

In order to show the image i need to set this

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 1920, 1080, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

Initially i was trying

```
 glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_BGRA, 1920, 1080, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

my understanding was that the second parameter is the format of the texel data provided to the function and the first is how to store it internally.

Are these formats linked to each other ?

Comment: `GL_BGRA` is not a valid internal format. See [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml). _format_ and _type_ specify the source image. _internalforamt_ specifies how the data is stored into the buffer.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank you now i understand why it was not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GL_BGRA` is not a valid internal format, see [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml). The *format* and *type* parameter specify the format of the source data. The *internalformat* parameter specifies the format of the target texture image.
When `glTexImage2D` is called, then the 2 dimensional texture image is specified and the source image converted to the internalformat of the target.